# Issues with For loops inside of Functions in Python 3.3

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Okay, so I'm working on writing a tic tac toe game, and have run into a pretty bad error that I can't seem to solve.  I have created a function that will have the computer block the player if the player is about to win, however, after if successfully blocks once, it doesn't trigger anymore even if the conditions are satisfied. The code for the function is:

```
def block():
for t in range(0, 9, 3):
        if slot[t] == user_team and slot[t+1] == user_team and (slot[t+2] \
           != user_team) and (slot[t+2] != computer_team):
            slot[int(t+2)] = computer_team
            return
        elif slot[t+1] == user_team and slot[t+2] == user_team and (slot[t] \
             != user_team) and (slot[t] != computer_team):
            slot[int(t)] = computer_team
            return
        elif slot[t] == user_team and slot[t+2] == user_team and (slot[t+1] \
             != user_team) and (slot[t+1] != computer_team):
            slot[int(t+1)] = computer_team
            return

for t in range(3):
        if slot[t] == user_team and slot[t+3] == user_team and (slot[t + 6] \
           != user_team) and (slot[t+6] != computer_team):
            slot[int(t+6)] = computer_team
            return
        elif slot[t+3] == user_team and slot[t+6] == user_team and (slot[t] \
             != user_team) and (slot[t] != computer_team):
            slot[int(t)] = computer_team
            return
        elif slot[t] == user_team and slot[t+6] == user_team and (slot[t+3] \
             != user_team) and (slot[t+3] != computer_team):
            slot[int(t+3)] = computer_team
```

Also, user_team and computer_team lead back to whether that player is X or O, and the `slot[int()] = computer_team` is used to place the move on the board.
And below is where the function is called (just in case I messed up here.):

```
else:
    draw_board()
    '''win()'''
    block()
    cmove()
    turn = "user"
    if end_game() == True:
        computer_win += 1
        draw_board()
        print ("The computer has won! But... We already knew that would happen. (:")
        playing = False
    elif end_game() == "Tie":
        tie_win += 1
        draw_board()
        print ("The game is a tie. You're going to have to try harder " \
               + "\n" + "if you wish to beat the computer!" + "\n")
        playing = False
    else:
        pass
```

If any of you could tell me where I went wrong, then that would make my day. c:

Board  (Prints are indented, it just doesn't want to here.)

```
def draw_board():
'''Opted to use lists so that the numbers can be replaced with either
    X or O later on and so that testing whether the game is over is simpler'''
print (" " + str(slot[0]) + " | " + str(slot[1]) + " | " + str(slot[2]))
print ("-----------")
print (" " + str(slot[3]) + " | " + str(slot[4]) + " | " + str(slot[5]))
print ("-----------")
print (" " + str(slot[6]) + " | " + str(slot[7]) + " | " + str(slot[8]))
print ("\n")
```

New ERRROR:

This is my board after I put in move 4

### X | O | X

### O | 4 | 5

### X | 7 | X

The computer's board after it's move 4 (two moves, and replaces an x)

### X | O | X

### O | 4 | O

### O | 7 | X

Comment: What is the error here? Please do include the full traceback.

Comment: Note that it is never *required* to use an `else:` suite with `if:`; the `else: pass` statements can be safely dropped.

Comment: There isn't really a tracebook because it doesn't produce an acutal "Error" per say. What happens is that after the computer blocks once, the program seems to just skip over the block() function. (if the conditions are satisfied, it won't make a move to stop the player from winning)

Comment: I don't see any conditions that may or may not work to call `block()` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Neither do I, which is why I'm confused. :O Would you like to look at the full source code?

Comment: So what does the computer do instead of blocking the player's winning move?

Comment: I'd rather you try to reduce the code to something that still exhibits the problem if you can. Also see http://ssce.org

Comment: Also, how are you representing the tic-tac-toe board? Is the first row(column) 0,1,2, the second row(column), 3,4,5, and the third row 6,7,8(column)?

Comment: @RobWatts It simply does nothing. I have the above code set up so that only block() runs during the computers turn. (cmove() only has a return in it, as it isn't coded yet).

            Edit: When I run it, block() isn't satisfied so it passes on to the players turn ( just so I can test block) and once the conditions are met, the computer will block when it is it's turn. However, after it blocks once, it will continue to only pass the turn to the player even if block() says it should make a move.

Comment: Hard to format comments, but that tells me what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: @RobWatts Put it in the original post!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll try and see if I can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the logic of your `block` function.

Here is your board:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Walking through the first pair of nested `for` loops, let's see what your code does:

```
for t in range(0,9,3):
    for y in range(1, 9, 3):
```

This will give you the follow pairs of `t, y`: (0,1), (0,4), (0,7), (3,1), (3,4), (3,7), (6,1), (6,4), and (6,7). Right away, I don't think this is what you had intended. From what I can tell, you are trying to check to see if the player has two marks in a row.

This problem is easy to fix - you don't need two `for` loops. Instead, just use `t`, `t+1`, and `t+2`.

Next, consider a row:

```
0 1 2
```

There are three conditions to check for, player has marks at 0 and 1, at 0 and 2, or at 1 and 2. You only check for two of these conditions - 0 and 1, and 1 and 2.

Additionally, the `if` statement isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
if ... and slot[y+1] != user_team and computer_team:
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
if ... and (slot[y+1] != user_team) and computer_team:
```

I assume `computer_team` is `'x'` or `'o'`, in which case python would use it the same as `True` in an `if` statement. What you want is this:

```
if ... and (slot[y+1] != user_team) and (slot[y+1] != computer_team):
```

This is also probably why your code would work only once - the next time it goes to evaluate the same row or column it found previously, the `if` statement will evaluate to `True` again, and it will set the same space again, which to you looks as if it is doing nothing.

Your code for checking the columns has the same issues. Hopefully the issues I've pointed out will be enough for you to figure out how to fix your code. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Those few changes really did wonders. c: I have, however ran into another error. ;O 

If the last two moves are in the two bottom corners (Only occurs in these two) then the computer will make a move, as well as a second move that replaces an X. I've updated the original post with the new block() function and the new error, if you don't mind reading over it again?

Comment: Never mind that error! I forgot to update my win() function since it had very identical structure to my old build.  Your suggestions have fixed all the issues i had. (: Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @GavinFeriancek if Rob fixed your problem, which it appears he worked hard to do, you should also accept his answer...

Comment: @beroe Good point! I just started using this site today, and didn't know about the green check till like 20 minutes ago. :P I've accepted it now, and am of course very thankful for all of the work he did. c:

Comment: Excellent. It is a small "price" to pay as a reward.

Comment: @beroe Tis not even considered a price! I spent hours upon hours trying to debug this, so a little check is nothing at all. c;